# AWS CloudWatch Query Result

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

The below code returns records when I run it in debug mode with a breakpoint on this line and stepping into the line. But when I run it in regular Run and do not step into this line, it produces 0 result.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
GetQueryResultsResult getQueryResultsResult = awslogs.getQueryResults(getQueryResultsRequest);
```

Comment: What happens if you put a logging statement immediately after? I wonder if your debug setup is using different AWS credentials, or a different AWS region? You can use **AWS CloudTrail** to see the API calls that are being made to your account to try and diagnose the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the below line of code, prior to that line of code, has fixed the issue:

*TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The query is not executed by the method `getQueryResults` of the `CloudWatchLogsClient`, is executed when you call `startQuery`.

The `startQuery` can take a long to finish its execution, so if you call the `getQueryResults` immediately after the `startQuery`, it won't get the results because the query may still be running.

So, to get the results, you can verify if the query is still running by checking the status of the `GetQueryResultsResponse` like this:

```
 GetQueryResultsResponse getQueryResultsResponse = null;
 do {
      getQueryResultsResponse = awslogs.getQueryResults(getQueryResultsRequest);
 } while ("Running".equals(getQueryResultsResponse.status().toString()));
```

Comment: could you share some working examples for 'StartQuery' and 'GetQueryResults' using java

Answer (score 0):

Use iterative "DescribeQueriesCommand" to check and wait until the query is in "Complete" state and then call the "GetQueryResultsCommand".

Calling the "GetQueryResultsCommand" iteratively only wastes the AWS CloudWatch Insights query limits.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/cloudwatch-logs/command/DescribeQueriesCommand/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).